# Contractibility of $\mathbb{R}^2$ when we remove the $x$-axis

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

> **Question:**  Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the $x$-axis contractible?

I'm doing differential equation and I have to decide if the domain is contractible, and I'm wondering if the above domain is.

Is it contractible because it is the real line?

Comment: (1) You should include your question in the body of your post.  Don't rely on people reading the title for context.  I have edited your post to fix this.  (2) Please provide some additional context.  What is your definition of "contractible"?  Do you have any thoughts on this problem?  Where does it come from (a text?  course notes?  if course notes, from which course?)?

Answer (score 4):

Every contractible space is connected.

$\qquad$[A contractible space is path connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715720/a-contractible-space-is-path-connected)

But if you remove a line from $\mathbb{R}^2$, the resulting space is not connected.

Comment: Your answer is just fine. Nevertheless, since it is evident that the OP is not familiar with Homotopy Theory, I think you should be a lot more generous in your argument ...

Comment: @Laz: I've added a link.